# Conditional if statements based on items in a list with python 3.x

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, conditional-statements, call

I am having difficulty getting this assignment to be functional without using anything we haven't "learned" yet...

I have to have a variable defined globally, eg:

```
x = [80, 70, 65, 60, 50, 40, 45, 40, 35, 7, 0]
```

given this global variable, I need to call its values with conditional statement to give a particular result. All I can think of based off what we have gone over in class is

```
x = [80, 70, 65, 60, 50, 40, 45, 40, 35, 7, 0]

if x >= 50:
    print("Good")
else:
    print("Bad")
```

and this simply will not work... But what I have got to work is the following:

```
for x in [80, 70, 65, 60, 50, 40, 45, 40, 35, 7, 0]:
    if x >= 50:
        print("Good")
    else:
        print("Bad")
```

This apparently is just simply not acceptable for the assignment though, due to the global variable is not defined as it should be. Also, the assignment deals with the turtle module, and the characteristics of the turtle will change based on the integer values in the list.

so now i come to answers given here already for an example more directly related to the assignment..

```
import turtle

def drawBar(t, height):
    t.begin_fill()
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.write('  '+ str(height))
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(40)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.left(90)
    t.end_fill()
    if height >= 50:
        t.fillcolor("blue")
    elif height < 50 and height >= 30:
        t.fillcolor("yellow")
    else:
        t.fillcolor("red")

xs = [80, 70, 65, 60, 50, 40, 45, 40, 70, 7, 0]

maxheight = max(xs)
numbars = len(xs)
border = 10

bob = turtle.Turtle()
bob.color("blue")
bob.pensize(3)

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")
wn.setworldcoordinates(0-border,0-border,40*numbars+border,maxheight+border)

for a in xs:
    drawBar(bob, a)

wn.exitonclick()
```

So now that I have it this far, the if statement doesn't accurately reflect the height of the bar for each bar in the program, it seems to give almost random colors, but the colors are always grouped together (which they shouldn't be). I need each bar to be a certain color based on its height, such as above 50 gets blue, less than 50 but equal or more than 30 yellow, everything else red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use the list in the `for` loop, like this:

```
for y in x:
    if y >= 50:
        print("Good")
    else:
        print("Bad")
```

**Update :**

Here is the updated `drawBar` function. The issue was, you have to set the `fillcolor` before drawing.

```
def drawBar(t, height):
    if height >= 50:
        t.fillcolor("blue")
    elif height < 50 and height >= 30:
        t.fillcolor("yellow")
    else:
        t.fillcolor("red")

    t.begin_fill()
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.write('  '+ str(height))
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(40)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.left(90)
    t.end_fill()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Worked perfectly.. I feel like an idiot now that the only issue was that I put it at the end of the function before it started the fill, makes so much more sense now... Glad you like my graph!

Answer (score 4):

```
for a in x:
    if a >= 50:
        print("Good")
    else:
        print("Bad")
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Make sure your "a" variable is actually an integer:

```
>>> str(1)>=5
True
```

Comment: ok, so it seems this works for this particular example just fine, but going to the turtle module, it stops.. so if i were to say in the if/else statement, if a >= 50: bob.fillcolor("blue") else: bob.fillcolor("red"), it always fills with blue...

Comment: @JustinTennant: It's impossible to answer this question without details of what the turtle module is and what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: Understandable, I have edited to give a better example of exactly what needs to be done

Comment: @JustinTennant: What you need to do is put the `if height >= 50: t.fillcolor("blue")` etc code *inside* the `drawBar` function.

Comment: `str(1)>=5` behaves differently in Python3 (Raises a `TypeError`). This is a good idea precisely because of the bugs that can slip by the way Python2 behaves

Comment: @David Robinson: Ok, so that definitely helps me get in the right direction, but since the function has height going down included as the height variable, when i set it to color the bars based on the height in the function, it does not accurately color based on the max value of the height :(

Comment: Set a global variable for the maximum height. Or you can use `a=[0,1,2,3,4], max(a),>>>4`

Comment: @Ophion: In this programs case, if i set a global variable for max height, it only reads from the highest value in the list, and makes all my bars turn the same color, i need to have the color of the individual bars show different based on the fill height of that bar, and each bar represent the value presented in the list x

Comment: So you can make the statement `maxheight-height`. At this point it is very difficult to understand what is happening in your program.

Comment: sorry about the vagueness, but i updated the question to show the entire program now. As it is with how far I have got, some bars are different colors now, but they are not the correct colors for all of them, and the first bar doesn't even fill any color.

Comment: @JustinTennant Check my answer for working solution... BTW, you have a nice graph there :)

Comment: @Ophion: Your first answer answered exactly what I asked, so thanks! Its just what I asked wasn't what I actually wanted XD